# Generate IReport / Jasper Report containing 2-page report (with 3 columns each) on a single sheet in landscape mode

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm doing a report for a client and I am not able to mount it according to your need. What he needs is to generate an A4 sheet of PDF in landscape mode, each containing sheet two pages (odd and even), and each page with 3 columns.

Already researched in various forums (both here in JUG as in others) but none could find something to help me with this resolution, and I'm already late with the delivery of this software, where only lack this report the products.

To illustrate better, I am sending this post the image of the result I need.

Please staff, someone knows and / or ever needed to generate a report of two pages on one single sheet? The 3 columns I can generate, but only on 1 page.

If you have any idea or suggestion to also otherwise to generate, will be very welcome, because my chances are very close to exhausted, so I need, and your help.

I'm using version 5.6.0 IReport

Answer (score 1):

Add a one more detail band and those three columns which you would like to show in second page. Adding detail bands makes adding different pages.

Comment: adding a detail band is really helpful :)